# C# Windows 10 IoT get xbox 360 controller input

Tags: c#, joystick, windowsiot

I have a Raspberry pi 3 with Windows 10 IoT installed, and I'm trying to make a background app that read input from a usb xbox 360 controller to later control servo motors. However I'm not really sure how to get the input. I that in windows you can use XNA, but I also know it has been discontinued and I don't even think it's avaible of windows IoT. Also apparently I can use both `Windows.Gaming.Input` and `Windows.Devices.Input`. What is the difference?
EDIT: apparently `Windows.Gaming.Input` works on a windows 10 pc, but not on the raspberry even if I use the exact same app with same source code

Comment: Did you solve the problem? Do you use the cable-bound or the wireless XBox 360 controller?

Comment: @Tobonaut I'm sorry, I was not able to. I ended up ditching the crapload that is Win10 IoT and instead use raspbian. It's a much better platform and I was able to use the controller with just some python scripting

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I still hope, that I can fix it.